# Owl identification

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This evening I spotted this beautiful owl that had become the centre of concern of my neighbourhood birds. There was a joint commotion of the House crows, Jungle bablers, Bulbuls and Maynas, which is still going on.

I wonder if this is a female Common Barn Owl.

[image]

Location: West Bengal, India.

P.S. I couldn't get better pictures.

Comment: That appears to be a [barn owl, *Tyto alba*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_owl).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the picture, this is a **Barn Owl** (*Tyto alba*). There are several [subspecies](https://www.barnowlbox.com/barn-owls-around-the-world/) of Barn Owl, 35 in fact. This bird is most likely the subspecies "stertens" also known as the Indian Barn Owl.

[image]

As to whether it is a female. It is dependent on the size and a few other features that cannot be determined in these photos.

> Females significantly larger than males in body mass, total length, beak length, tarsus length, foot length and width, and wing loading, but not in wing chord or tail length ( [Marti 1990a](https://sora.unm.edu/sites/default/files/journals/condor/v092n01/p0261-p0263.pdf) ). Female plumage typically darker than that of males but sexes overlap in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [barn owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_owl). This is probably the most common owl in India and is found in most of peninsular India.